# pythonでTFlearnがインポートできないです。

Tags: python, 機械学習, tensorflow, 深層学習

Mac book で『初めてのTensorFlow』と言う本にしたがってTFlearnをインストールしたのですがいざpythonでインポートしようとすると下のような表示が出てしまいます。
解決方法をぜひ教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

```
Shiraishi-Sadaaki-no-Macbook-ea:~ shiraishisadaaki$ python
Python 3.5.0 (default, Jun 14 2017, 14:38:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tflearn
/Users/shiraishisadaaki/.pyenv/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/shiraishisadaaki/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the retry module or similar alternatives.
>>> import tflearn
```

Comment: 出ているメッセージを見る限り警告 (Warning) のみでエラーが出ていないように見えます。`import tflearn` 自体は成功しているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、回答ありがとうございます!!エラーではなく警告ということはこのまま使っていても不具合は起きないということですか？？

Comment: その点について、回答として投稿いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

今回出ているメッセージは2つとも警告 (Warning) であり、エラーではありません。また、どちらの警告も TFlearn を動かすために使われている関数が将来のバージョンアップによって使えなくなる (deprecated である) ことを言っているだけであり、今すぐに影響があるとまでは言っていません。更新頻度が高いパッケージを使う際、依存しているパッケージたちのバージョンが頻繁に上がることで API が変わり、このような警告が出ることはよくあることです。

したがって、これらの警告は無視できます。何かしら他のエラーが出ない限り現在のまま使い続けることができます。

ただし将来的にはエラーに繋がるため、警告をずっと放っておくのはあまり行儀がよくありません。どうしても警告を消したければ、以下の方法が思いつきます。

1. TFlearn のバージョンを最新版にする。今回のような警告は TFlearn の開発者によって解決され、最新版では直っている可能性があります。
2. 最新版でも直っていない場合、TFlearn の [contribution ガイド](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn#contributions)を参考に、issue トラッカーへ報告する。